# Best way to implement user-rearrangable buttons in a scrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uiswitch

At the moment I'm doing it by having 'slots' which will be assigned buttons, which are read from a plist. E.g.,

```
switch ([slot1 intValue]) {
            case 1:
                button1 = [wtb twitterButtonType];
                [button1 addGestureRecognizer:twitterButtonTap];
                break;
            case 2:
                button1 = [wtb facebookButtonType];
                [button1 addGestureRecognizer:faceBookButtonTap];
                break;
            case 3:
                button1 = [wtb SMSButtonType];
                [button1 addGestureRecognizer:smsButtonTap];
                break;
            case 4:
                button1 = [wtb phoneButtonType];
                [button1 addGestureRecognizer:instaCallButtonTap];
                break;
            case 5:
                button1 = [wtb cameraButtonType];
                [button1 addGestureRecognizer:cameraButtonTap];
                break;
            case 6:
                button1 = [wtb torchButtonType];
                [button1 addGestureRecognizer:flashButtonTap];
                break;
            case 7:
                button1 = [wtb pastieButtonType];
                [button1 addGestureRecognizer:pastieButtonTap];
                break;
            case 8:
                button1 = [wtb powerButtonType];
                [button1 addGestureRecognizer:powerButtonTap];
                break;
            default:
                button1 = nil;
                allocSlot1 = NO;
                break;
        }
```

Now I am almost 100% certain this is not the way to do it, as you can imagine, with more than a few slots, that spaghetti up there quickly gets out of hand. So my question is: what is the conventional way of doing what I'm trying?

Comment: There really isn't much of a "convention", I don't think. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do - can you give a screenshot or the name of another app that does what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's for a jailbreak tweak that adds some common functions to Notification Centre. It works using this method, I was just wondering if there was a better way. Here's a screenshot: http://d.pr/vKrg

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do in a larger context - but I think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a similar UI in the [500px iPad app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/500px/id471965292) - a series of buttons in a  scroll view. I found [this tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html) very helpful; it describes how to create this kind of "infinite" looping scroll view with a limited number of views.

The plist seems overkill, but it might make sense if you expect users to edit it to control content. I think if you're going to have dynamic content, that's probably the way to go. If it's always the same buttons, you can just add buttons as instance variables, or even an array of instance variables.